# remove img tag src is a url using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, html

Hi I would like to remove a img tag with it's src is a url in a content using preg_replace

ex.

```
    $content = "<center><img src="http://example.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cell-degeneration-contn.jpg" alt="" title="cell-degeneration-contn" width="950" height="272" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-100" /></center><h2>A first-in-class approach to stop & reverse </h2>";
```

so output would be:

```
    $content="<center></center><h2>A first-in-class approach to stop & reverse </h2>";
```

but best output would be if possible is :

```
    $content="A first-in-class approach to stop & reverse ";
```

Comment: Does it *have* to use preg_replace?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  As Marc B pointed it seems that regex is not the way to operate html text; just clarify if you really to use need preg_replace

Answer (score 2):

[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) would work here, but with HTML it's not the most efficient.

```
$content = '<center><img src="http://example.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cell-degeneration-contn.jpg" alt="" title="cell-degeneration-contn" width="950" height="272" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-100" /></center><h2>A first-in-class approach to stop & reverse </h2>';

preg_match("/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/",$content,$matches);
$output = $matches[1];
echo $output;
```

The easiest way is to just use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$output = strip_tags($content);
echo $output;
```

Comment: why preg_match_all and not preg_match ? :-??

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way:

```
    $content = "<center><img src='http://example.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cell-degeneration-contn.jpg' alt='' title='cell-degeneration-contn' width='950' height='272' class='alignnone size-full wp-image-100' /></center><h2>A first-in-class approach to stop & reverse </h2>'";
    preg_match("/<h2>(.+)<\/h2>/", $content, $matches);  
    $match = $matches[1];
    echo $match;
```